# Oracle APEX - Region Display selector - selecting a specific tab

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to figure out how to select a specific tab under Region Display Selector based on a hidden page item.

I have a RDS with a bunch of regions under it and a hidden page item that contains a value - region name. By default, when page is accessed, the last selected region is showing but I need to select a region based on the hidden page item.

I have tried the following javascript:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(".&APP_ID..&APP_PAGE_ID..RDS.activeTab","#CR_SR_TAB_1");
$('#RDS a[href="#CR_SR_TAB_1"]').trigger('click');
```

but that did not work.

Comment: This looks a little different to what I see described https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2018/11/27/apex-quickie-set-region-display-selector-dynamically/ but it could be a version thing. Did you check what's referenced in the browser tools? Where did you execute this script?

Comment: Or you could use a solution similar to this https://community.oracle.com/message/14611559